# How do I remove all the ending caret characters from a string?

Tags: java, regex

How do I remove all the ending caret characters from end of a string?

For example:  I have a string with value `"t^e^st ^^^^^^^^"`
My output should be `"t^e^st"`.  How can I do this using Java regex?

Comment: Is there always a space after the word before the final carets?

Comment: If there is always a final space, then just `String[] splitString = str.split("\\s+");` is fine, no regex required, then just get first element

Comment: So, we know to start with a regular expression: which pattern(s) have been tried? With which method(s)? How did such work or not work?

Answer (score 2):

```
"t^e^st ^^^^^^^^".replaceAll("\\^*$", '')
```

The caret also needs to be escaped. `\\s*` takes care of any trailing whitespace also.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and  t^e^st ^^^^^^^^".replaceAll("\\^*$","") also gives me the same result not sure why do we need \\s part

Comment: I just added that because you did not specify whether the whitespace is always at the end or not. Makes sense? If it worked then please accept. I hope you went through the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Actually the \\s is not needed. I misunderstood that there may be whitespace at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try anchoring a repeated ^ to the end of the String, like this:

`"t^e^st ^^^^^^^^".replaceAll("(.*)\\^*$", "$1").trim();`

This looks for and captures any characters (`(.*)`) that are followed by 0 or more carats (`\\^*`) at the end of the string (`$`). Then it replaces all of that with the first capture group (`$1`) and trims the string to remove any leading/trailing spaces. The result should be just `"t^e^st"`.

Comment: Shouldn't the caret also be escaped?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but "t^e^st ^^^^^^^^".replaceAll("(.*)^*$", "$1").trim(); didn't work its not removing the ^

Comment: @AseemBansal yes, it should be escaped, I'll fix that.